# MySQL: Product Current Lowest Price/Previous Lowest Price Percent Difference

Tags: mysql

I have a two tables, one stores the current lowet price `v_prod_prices` and `td_prod_prices` that has all the price updates for all products, the function below is meant to get the percent difference between the current lowest price and the previous lowest price. I'm almost there just a small bit of logic I can't figure out.

**Current Output**

The function at present is returning `-71.42` which is incorrect as it's using the current price of `10.00` which is correct and the previous price of `34.99` which is incorrect.

**Expected/Desired Output**

It should return `-50` by using the current price of `10.00` and the previous lowest price which would be `20.00` in this instance.

These records would be ignored from `td_prod_prices` when getting the previous lowest price:

```
id      prod_id price   store   added
-----------------------------------------------
734     426     10.00   1       2016-01-22 02:05:17
819     426     42.99   3       2016-01-24 23:47:51
1052    426     34.99   4       2016-01-27 00:54:50
```

**v_prod_prices**

The view `v_prod_prices` contains only the current lowest price per product per store based off the `td_prod_prices` table.

```
prod_id price   store   added
-------------------------------------------
426     34.99   4       2016-01-27 00:54:50
426     42.99   3       2016-01-24 23:47:51
426     10.00   1       2016-01-22 02:05:17
426     29.19   2       2016-01-15 14:09:53
```

**td_prod_prices**

`td_prod_prices` contains all the product price updates.

```
id      prod_id price   store   added
-----------------------------------------------
500     426     29.19   2       2016-01-15 14:09:53
660     426     20.00   1       2016-01-15 21:07:38
734     426     10.00   1       2016-01-22 02:05:17
819     426     42.99   3       2016-01-24 23:47:51
1052    426     34.99   4       2016-01-27 00:54:50
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_GET_PROD_PRICE_CHANGE_DIFF (`prodId` BIGINT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `priceDiff` DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `currentPrice`, `previousPrice` DOUBLE(7,2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `currentStore`, `previousStore` INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `currentAdded`, `previousAdded` TIMESTAMP;

    /* Get current price */
    SELECT MIN(`price`)
    , `store`
    , `added`
    INTO `currentPrice`
    , `currentStore`
    , `currentAdded`
    FROM `v_prod_prices`
    WHERE `prod_id` = `prodId`
    LIMIT 0,1;

    /* Get previous price */
    SELECT MIN(`spr`.`spr_price`) AS `price`
    , `spr`.`spr_str_id` AS `store`
    , `spr`.`spr_added` AS `added`
    INTO `previousPrice`
    , `previousStore`
    , `previousAdded`
    FROM `td_prod` `prod`
    JOIN `td_prod_prices` `spr` ON `prod`.`prod_id` = `spr`.`spr_prod_id`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM `td_prod_prices` `spr2`
        WHERE `spr`.`spr_prod_id` = `spr2`.`spr_prod_id`
        AND `spr`.`spr_str_id` = `spr2`.`spr_str_id`
        AND `spr`.`spr_added` < `spr2`.`spr_added`
    )
    AND `prod`.`prod_status` = 1
    AND `prod`.`prod_id` = prodId;

    IF `currentPrice` <> 0 AND `previousPrice` <> 0 AND `currentPrice` <> `previousPrice` THEN
        SET `priceDiff` = ((`currentPrice` - `previousPrice`) / `previousPrice`) * 100;
    END IF;

    RETURN `priceDiff`;
END//
```

Comment: Given the sample data set, what should be the desired result?

Comment: @Strawberry, the desired result is in the question under `Expected/Desired Output`.

Comment: I don't understand which is the difference between `v_prod_prices` and `td_prod_prices`, nor how you define that 20 is the correct previous price (choice depends on which criterion?).

Comment: @cFreed, I've clarified the details in the question. The view `v_prod_prices` contains only the current lowest price on a per product per store basis off with all the data coming from the `td_prod_prices` table, `td_prod_prices` table contains all price updates for the product, hope that's clearer. 20 is the previous lowest price based on the `added` timestamp as it was the lowest price before 10 became the lowest price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working eventually, posting here for future reference for anyone in a similar situation. I changed it to get the `id` of the current lowest price record and the exclude any records greater then or equal to that `id` when calculating the previous lowest price of the product.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_GET_PROD_PRICE_CHANGE_DIFF (`prodId` BIGINT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `priceDiff` DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `currentPriceId` BIGINT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE `currentPrice`, `previousPrice` DOUBLE(7,2) DEFAULT 0;

    /* Get current price */
    SELECT `price_id`
    , `price`
    INTO `currentPriceId`
    , `currentPrice`
    FROM `v_prod_prices`
    WHERE `prod_id` = `prodId`
    ORDER BY `price` ASC
    LIMIT 0,1;

    /* Get previous price */
    SELECT `spr`.`spr_price` AS `price`
    INTO `previousPrice`
    FROM `td_prod` `prod`
    JOIN `td_prod_prices` `spr` ON `prod`.`prod_id` = `spr`.`spr_prod_id`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM `td_prod_prices` `spr2`
        WHERE `spr`.`spr_prod_id` = `spr2`.`spr_prod_id`
        AND `spr`.`spr_str_id` = `spr2`.`spr_str_id`
        AND `spr`.`spr_added` < `spr2`.`spr_added`
        AND `spr`.`spr_added` > `currentAdded`
        AND `spr2`.`spr_id` < `currentPriceId`
    )
    AND `prod`.`prod_status` = 1
    AND `prod`.`prod_id` = prodId
    AND `spr`.`spr_id` < `currentPriceId`
    ORDER BY price ASC
    LIMIT 0,1;

    IF `currentPrice` <> 0 AND `previousPrice` <> 0 AND `currentPrice` <> `previousPrice` THEN
        SET `priceDiff` = ((`currentPrice` - `previousPrice`) / `previousPrice`) * 100;
    END IF;

    RETURN `priceDiff`;
END//
```